# How to do conversion from LESS to SCSS?

Tags: css, sass, less, mixins

Seems sass-convert is done converting LESS to SCSS based on search results. I used the following LESS in past projects:

```
// Examples of how to use .box-shadow mixin
//.box-shadow (1px 1px 3px 0, 35%, 0, 0, 0);
//.box-shadow (1px 1px 3px 0, #000);
//.box-shadow (inset 1px 1px 3px 0, #000);
.box-shadow (@style, @color) when (iscolor(@color)) {
    -webkit-box-shadow: @arguments;
       -moz-box-shadow: @arguments;
            box-shadow: @arguments;
}
.box-shadow (@style, @alpha: 50%, @R: 0, @G: 0, @B: 0) when (isnumber(@alpha)) {
    .box-shadow (@style, rgba(@R, @G, @B, @alpha));
}
```

Pointers, greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: BTW, Compass provides mixins for just about everything that requires prefixes (see http://compass-style.org/)

Comment: "Conversion from LESS to SCSS" =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approximate conversion, I don't think you can do conditions on mixin parameters in SASS. You will get a warning when putting certain values into rules, for example it complained when it tried to compile `50%` in `rgba()` as it needs to be from `0` to `1`.

```
@mixin box-shadow($style, $color) {
    -webkit-box-shadow: unquote($style) $color;
       -moz-box-shadow: unquote($style) $color;
            box-shadow: unquote($style) $color;
}
@mixin box-shadow-rgba($style, $r: 0, $g: 0, $b: 0, $alpha: 0.5) {
    @include box-shadow($style, rgba($r, $g, $b, $alpha));
}

// Usage    
div {
    @include box-shadow-rgba('inset', 255, 0, 0);
}
```

Compiles to:

```
div {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: inset rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5); }
```

Comment: Darn... so it seems there's now iscolor() & isnumber() equivalent in SASS/SCSS; and we'll need to 2 different mixins: `box-shadow` & `box-shadow-rgba`. LESS: 1. SASS: 0. =\

Okay--thanks! Learning a lot by doing and getting examples.